# How to get category image based on category ID?

Tags: product, category, category-id, category-image

I am trying to get an image which is uploaded for the category.

& also

I have category id and want to load complete details of that category based on category ID.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Block with two functions. one for get category image by categoryID and another function for get category data by categoryId .

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\CategoryFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Mycategoryinfo extends  \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category
     */
    protected $categoryHelper;


   /**
   * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository
   */
   protected $categoryRepository;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
         StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;        
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * get category image
     * @param int categoryId
     * @return string Imageurl
     */
    public function getImageByCategoryId($categoryId){
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
        $imageurl = $category->getImageUrl();       
        return $imageurl;        
    }



    /**
     * 
     * get category Data
     * @param int categoryId
     * @return array 
     */
    public function getCategoryById($categoryId){
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);        
        return $category->getData();
    }




}
```